# Veda error: 401

Tags: veda-soft

При  установки *Веда* (интерактивная система дистанционного обучения) на хостинг возникла проблема.
Я поставил *ioncube*, подключил БД, но получаю ошибку:

> Veda error: 401

Почему возникает ошибка?

Comment: Виндовое приложение, для которого предпочтительным браузером является Apple Safari - это несколько необычно.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка *Veda error: 401* означает ошибку при чтении конфигурационного файла. В консоли, при запуске, указано более подробно в чем именно проблема. Или файла нет «Configuration file 'veda.conf' not found» или в синтаксисе ошиблись «Configuration parameter is incorrect». Подробно, как исправлять, написано в [инструкции](http://www.veda-soft.com/download.php?id=usermanual_ru) на странице 51.

Comment: Когда веду запускаешь, остается консолька открыта, туда она все ошибки "валит". Веда только на "Винде" работает, на shared-хостинге её не запустить, только на виндовом сервере если.

Comment: Как понять "при запуске, в консоли"? Система находится онлайн. Т.е. развернута на хостинге (т.е. идут попытки развернуть её онлайн). А иначе для чего она локальная? Локально работает она отлично, переписан в "config.veda" лишь пароль к БД и адрес. И при чём тут файл "veda.conf"? Он же для старта системы на локальном ПК?

Comment: Как понимающему суть вопроса, тогда вопрос. Что в ней такого, что она так "привязана" к офису? Для чего компания так разработала движок. Спрошу прямо - коммерческий шпионаж? Или что-то мирное? Но для чего?

Comment: Я не особо в курсе, помогал товарищу Веду поднимать. Наверное, так проще.